# how to synchronize the rotation of the icosphere

Tags: geometry-nodes

Hello i want to synchronise the postion of the icsphere with the x coordinate of the cube .Please Tell me how can i make it .[image] here is my blend file[image]new screenshoot  [image]

Comment: i think you uploaded my blend file from my old answer....

Comment: Please check  with your file.

Comment: I don't know how  to sychronise. May you englight me please.

Comment: your uploaded file is wrong. just delete it and upload again.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i strongly recommend using some kind of translation tool - e.g. https://translate.google.com/?hl=en

Comment: It looks like an issue on the math side. What is driving your green object ? How is it possible your icosphere isn't on the same trigonometric angle ? Are they both driven by the same maths ?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: if you would have taken a closer look, you could see that he edited his question in the meantime....

Comment: As of now, blend file and screenshot don't show the same node tree. @KebabSharif please edit your question with correct blend file or screenshot.

Comment: Lutzi please  check .. In screen shoot i just deleted some un connected nodes. That's all .

Comment: Now please some one help out to synchronise.Thank you .

Comment: So at the end no one has  given me a solution. So please help me .